# Resuming incremental SSIS CDC sync with big CDC "backlog"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, change-data-capture

We're using an SSIS package which syncs changes from one (main) database to another (reporting) using CDC. The package runs periodically syncing the data in small increments.

After having an issue with the package not working for a long period of time we have a big backlog in the CDC tables now.

Just running the package for the entire backlog will time out because of the amount of data.
So we're looking for a way to process the CDC "backlog" in pieces.

The current CDC implementation is using the SSIS [CDC control task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/cdc-control-task) with the GetProcessingRange operation to establish the CDC LSN range for the data flows that do the sync.

GetProcessingRange appears to always set the range from the first unprocessed LSN to the end including all the data in the CDC tables, which is not what we need as I described above.

Any suggestions on how to process a big CDC "backlog" in pieces in an SSIS package are appreciated.

Comment: What is the size of the backlog compared to the full data size? Sometimes reinitializing from scratch is the easiest solution after a long disruption

Comment: @AMtwo, The full data size is much bigger (100 times or more), the initial sync when we did it took a long time.